# is it efficient to have a global variable when using multiprocessing?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Please consider this cool setup:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def helper(master_df):
    max_index = master_df['key'].max()
    min_index = master_df['key'].min()
    #note how slave is defined before running the multiprocessing
    return slave.iloc[min_index:max_index,]

from datetime import datetime

master = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
slave = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                      'value' : ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']})

if __name__ == '__main__':
     startTime = datetime.now()
     p = Pool(cpu_count() - 1)
     ret_list = p.map(helper, [master.iloc[1:5,], master.iloc[5:10,]])
     print datetime.now() - startTime
     print ret_list
```

Essentially, I have two dataframes in memory.

As you can see in the main multiprocessing code, `p.map` receives, as arguments, two chunks of the `master` dataframe.

Then, (I imagine) each process spawned by `multiprocessing` will access the `slave` dataframe and use it (without modifying). Indeed, you can see in the `helper` function that each process will `slice` the `slave` dataframe and do some computation with it.

My question is: is it efficient to have a dataframe defined in the global namespace that is accessed by each process? I am not sure what happens in terms of RAM utilization (is `slave` duplicated in memory for each process?). That would not be a good idea, because in reality both `master` and `slave` are really big.

I guess one alternative would be to send a `tuple` to `p.map` that contains the chunked `master` AND the corresponding sliced `slave` dataframe. Not sure is this is a good idea (and how to do it properly)?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This surprisingly depends on the operating system, as [`multiprocessing` is implemented differently in Windows and Linux](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2010/python-multiprocessing-linux-windows/).

- In Linux, under the hood, processes are created via a `fork` variant where the child process shares the same address as the parent, initially, and then performs COW (copy on write). Under Linux, I've often had child processes access a read-only global DataFrame, and everything was fine (including performance).
- In Windows, under the hood, apparently, a whole process is spun up, and you might have a performance penalty of copying the DataFrame to it (unless processing done by it is large enough to render the cost negligible), but I haven't ever used Python on Windows, so have no experience with it.

**Edit**

An example of using [`joblib`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/) with DataFrames:

```
import joblib
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 3], b=[2, 3]))

def foo(i, df):
    return df + i

from joblib import Parallel, delayed
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(foo)(i, df) for i in range(10))
```

You could also use `df` as a global:

```
def foo(i):
    return df + i

from joblib import Parallel, delayed
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(foo)(i) for i in range(10))
```

Comment: COW has problems with the reference counts dirtying pages

Comment: very cool. so I guess the safest bet is to send a tuple with both chunks. Do you know how to do that properly in Python 2.7? Thanks!!

Comment: @ThomasGrainger That is a good point. As always with performance, things depend on the settings, and YMMV.

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ AFAIR it should just work out of the box, but if not, there are some tricks with joblib and dill that are possible. Come to think of it, if that's how you're going, I recommend using joblib. LMK if you run into problems.

Comment: my comment was posted as an asnwer... vannoy delete it on my phone. anyway  can you please try to code up what you suggest with my small toy example? thanks!!!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Can you have a look at the first example in https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html?

Comment: i can but I am asking this for the sake of having a nice answer on SO directly :)

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I'll write one tomorrow.

Comment: Hello @AmiTavory I imagine you are super busy, but can you try to write up your answer when possible? thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, sure - a bit later, though.

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Hey, added an example.